# If Kanji are necessary to disambiguate homophones, how come it's still used, being that Japanese people seem to know the difference when speaking?

Tags: kanji, homophonic-kanji, furigana, pitch-accent, written-language

I'm a beginner.

People argue for Kanji being that it helps disambiguate homophones in written Japanese, but in spoken Japanese, kanji (or any other visual aid) are not available, yet people seem to know the difference between [話]{はな}す, [離]{はな}す, [放]{はな}す, [映]{は}える, 生{は}える, and so forth. So why are Kanji necessary to disambiguate homophones if people know how to disambiguate them in spoken Japanese where Kanji aren't available? And can the same thing be applied to written Japanese?

In that case, why can't I write 私は学生です as わたしはがくせいです or use spaces like わたし_は_がくせい_です ? Or use pitch accent markers in writing like [わたしはがくせいです]{LHHLHLHLHL} (I don't know if this pitch accent notation is correct), or add furigana above particle markers to indicate their pronunciation (like [は]{わ} and [を]{お}), or a combination of these? In short, why are Kanji necessary?

Comment: +1 to counter downvote. Although this question seem to assume that the only reason for using Kanji is to disambiguate homophones, which I'm not sure to be a correct assumption, this is a well written question and I don't really see a problem with it. Unless it is a duplicate, perhaps. The asker showed to have a minimum knowledge and presented a few arguments to explain his thoughts, so I don't think this question deserved an unexplained downvote.

Comment: Also, related question on Linguistics.SE: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3831/

Comment: I would think that in technical document, scientific papers, and academic papers, kanji can clarify meaning in a way that could possibly be completely obscured if it were written in just kana.

Comment: The idea has actually been discussed since the 19th century. 漢字廃止論 (Kanji-haishi-ron) is the related term, although I'm not sure if reliable sources are available in English.

Comment: In English, many homonyms are different parts of speech: *red* vs *read*, *reed* vs *read* and thus clearly distinguishable; others like *heart* vs *hart* (an uncommon word) or *dough* vs *doe* are easily distinguished even in a minimal context.... though I do recall once reading a novel in which the author used the verb *bow* in a deliberately unclear manner: whether the author meant *bow* as in to play a violin or to greet someone was skillfully left open to interpretation--though in this case these two words are not homonyms though spelled identically.

Comment: I think the corresponding question in English relates to our alphabet.  We have redundant consonants and too few vowels to correctly represent the spoken language. We could get by without 'c' or 'q', but although this would be a much smaller change than ditching kanji, there would still be tremendous pushback.

Comment: I know this will be mis-interpreted and/or disliked. I don't hate kanji. But the fact that it takes like 9 years of study for a Japanese child to become literate suggests um, well something :P  Similarly we have Korean as an example where every year less and less kanji is used. Kanji is beautiful but ...

Comment: @gman We use kanji not because it's beautiful but because it's practical and more efficient in total when you take it into account educating technical experts. You should check how some Korean themselves are worried about their own practical literacy for technical terms.

Comment: More efficient relative to what? How is 8 more years spent studying kanji rather than say STEM more efficient? You've got a country, Korea, that's about as close culturally to Japan as possible (is there one more close?) and they pretty much got rid of kanji and they don't appear to be any less efficient than Japanese. The point being there's an example getting rid of kanji. I'm not saying I personally want to get rid of it. I'm just pointing out it's not hypothetical. It has happened once.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

## Kanji aren't necessary to write Japanese

Your rationale is correct; Japanese is a living, spoken language; people are able to understand each other by sound only, therefore a writing system based on sound *has* to be sufficient.

Some commentators have mentioned that Japanese speakers often allude to kanji when talking.  That's true enough (and it probably reflects something deep about how the mental lexicon is organized¹); but explicit references to kanji remain a minor cultural fact, not a necessary feature of the language.  There exists blind people in Japan, for example; the congenitally blind will never have seen a single kanji, and they're nonetheless fluent Japanese speakers.  As a Brazilian, I've personally met several Japanese-Brazilians who learned the language from birth, but who never learned the writing system; they could interact with native Japanese people just fine (who'd often be surprised to learn they were born in Brazil), and I'll go ahead and assert they're native speakers, too.  One does not *have* to know kanji to be a Japanese speaker.

We also have several types of sound-based, Japanese text works, so we know it can be done. @Kurausukun's example of children-oriented videogames (and children's books, etc.) is a good point.  Other examples would include historical *kana* literature of the Heian period; Ishikawa Takuboku's *Rômazi Nikki* (written in Latin characters to prevent his wife from reading it – but easily readable by any Japanese speaker nowadays); and publications by associations like the various [Rômazi-kai](http://www.age.ne.jp/x/ork/) or [Kana-moji-kai](http://www.kanamozi.org/).

## Pitch accent isn't necessary to understand Japanese either

@Kurausukun and others have mentioned the common argument that pitch accent is necessary for sound-based understanding.  It's true that standard Tokyo Japanese distinguishes many words by accent alone (like the famous three-way distinction between *HÁshì-gà* = "the chopsticks"; *hàSHÍ-gà* = "the bridge"; *hàSHÍ-GÁ* = "the edge").  And true, it's a damn shame that they aren't usually marked in writing; accented rōmaji is, in my opinion, a severely underrated tool for beginning foreign students, and I wish it was the norm.

One has to keep in mind, however, that the "homogeneity" of Japanese is a myth.  The country has a large number of distinct dialects, and pitch accent in particular varies a lot between them (I'm doing research on accent, and I'd say the amount of variation from *the same speaker* is already significant…).  Some areas, including e.g. most of Fukushima or Miyazaki, feature no pitch accent at all (無型アクセント).  Given that people from these areas can understand each other, and that in general a Tokyoite can understand an Osaka comedian without much trouble despite their accents being unpredictably different, it has to be the case that pitch accent in writing isn't essential.

This should come as no surprise, since language is notoriously resilient.  Tone in Chinese is responsible for a lot more important distinctions than accent in Japanese, and yet Chinese people can read *pīnyīn* (Chinese romaji) without tone marks, and often don't bother writing them.  Vowels are certainly an important part of the English language, but yuu cuuld wrutu wuthuut vuwul dustunctuns und stull bu undurstuud must uf thu tumu.

## Written Japanese is different than spoken Japanese

That being said, there are still some reasons why Japanese people feel so strongly that kanji are important.

The first of them is that the vocabulary of written Japanese isn't the same as the spoken language.  To understand this, you have to switch your point of view inside out.  It's not that Japanese has so many homophones that it needs kanji to be written.  This is exactly backwards; what happens is that kanji **allows** one to write with lots of homophones, and *therefore* Japanese writing (and only writing) can use more homophones than normal.  The same is true of Literary Chinese, the (artificial, written) language for which kanji were designed.²  Chinese, too, is a spoken language (actually a large family of spoken languages), and as such is perfectly understandable by sound alone.  However, the Literary version was a kind of super-condensed Chinese that relied on the characters as support.  Reading Literary Chinese aloud wouldn't always result in something intelligible (unlike natural, spoken Chinese).

A big source of those Japanese homophones are precisely loanwords from that homophone-heavy Literary Chinese; these Chinese-style words are called *kango* in Japan.  Typical spoken Japanese has about 23% of *kango*; typical written Japanese has some 41%—almost double as much.³  The more formal, intellectual or specialized the language, the more it tends to use *kango*.

Due to this difference, if you just blindly convert a text made for kanji into kana or rōmaji, the result often feels clunky and hard to read.  The proper thing to do would be to replace *kango* vocabulary, bringing the written language closer to speech; this is called *iikae* by Japanese researchers.⁴  If the text is written without using kanji from the outset, the writer will instinctively choose adequate vocabulary, and *iikae* isn't necessary.

## Kanji can be cool

Finally, I think it's important to keep in mind that, just because kanji are not *necessary*, it doesn't mean they don't add something.  Reading kanji text *feels* different, and there are neurolinguistic reasons for that.⁵  And this means that the use of kanji has æsthetic, cultural, and subjective value.

Through their entire history, the tendency of the Japanese as a culture was never to try and make their writing simple and utilitarian, but rather to experiment, play, innovate with it.  They could just have used *kana* or *bonji* phonetic characters for everything since a thousand years ago – indeed Heian kana literature was an experiment with this – but opted instead to keep using kanji, and not only that, but to assign multiple readings to them, and mix them with kana in many ways.  The resulting system has always been explored creatively, to create many effects; not just in fancy works like the *Man'yōshū* (almost a puzzle-set of script play), but 
also in popular things like Edo-era folk literature or modern-day visual culture.

When Natsume Sōseki writes *tonikaku* as 兎に角, or *yakamashii* as 八釜しい, for example, he's making a kind of game with the reader, sharing a sort of intimacy with them.  When Anzai Fuyue writes a poem about a butterfly like this—

> てふてふが一匹韃靼海峡を渡って行った
>   A butterfly is travessing the Strait of Tartar and—gone.

—he's using the cognitive weight of kanji characters to cause an effect similar to what Western poets usually do with consonants and obstruents.  Natsuhiko Kyōgoku, a writer of detective fiction, relies heavily on archaic kanji and unusual furigana for atmosphere; he'd lose a lot if merely converted to kana.  All sorts of linguistic and æsthetic effects can be created with the inventive interplay of kanji and kana and furigana…

[image: No Game no Life "kuuhaku"]
[image: Tokyo Tabearu-ki]
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

…and this sort of thing is *extremely* common.  It doesn't occur just in elevated poems and classical literature, but happens right now in the most popular of forms: in manga, in videogames, in advertisements, in song lyrics, in baby naming… So I'd claim that the Japanese have a living, thriving culture of kanji, and I find it perfectly reasonable that they consistently reject the idea of killing it.

References:

1. Terry Joyce, *Modeling  the Japanese Mental Lexicon* (& further research).
2. Victor Mair, [*Buddhism and the rise of the written vernacular in East Asia*](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2059728).
3. Miyaji and Kai.  「日本語学」特集テーマ別ファイル　語彙３：語種論／和語。
4. Sachiko Matsunaga. *The linguistic and psycholinguistic nature of kanji*.
5. Zev Handel. *Logography and the classification of writing systems: a response to Unger.*

Comment: I'd had that kanjis can hold a nuance that may not be obvious when speaking. More specifically, there are homophones that look like they are the same word but aren't. For instance, 探【さが】すand 捜【さが】す both mean "to look for", but the former is used when looking for something that has not been discovered yet, while the latter bears the meaning of something lost (correct me if I'm wrong though). The same goes with 見【み】る/診【み】る/視【み】る/観【み】る, which all mean something related to sight. In a nutshell: kanjis are cool.

Comment: The Americans observed that in POW camps, when they gave German newspapers to Germans, one of them would read for the others, while the Japanese would distribute the paper, everyone reading for themselves.

Comment: This is a great answer! I think one detail that could be added though is kanji's enhanced ability to expand vocabulary. If someone had a native or sufficiently thorough background in kanji, seeing a new word written in kanji can quickly help them to ascertain its meaning. I've often compared it to how learning Greek and Latin roots will help one understand difficult vocabulary in English.

Comment: I have to say, the use of the underrated æ for aesthetic is _especially_ on point for this answer.

Comment: One thing I think you overlooked: spoken Japanese is usually spoken in *dialogue*, where you have plenty of context and can ask for clarification if needed. In some situations where you might not hear perfectly and can't ask for clarification, such as TV shows, there are often "subtitles" of a sort that include kanji. So it's not even necessarily true that Japanese speakers can understand each other "perfectly fine" without kanji, just well enough. Kanji are an aid, as well as supporting/enabling the nuances in written text as you pointed out.

Comment: @SirTechSpec the use of subtitles on TV is an interesting phenomenon; I myself prefer to watch shows in English or my native Portuguese with same-language captions, when they're available (bless you, opensubtitles.org). However, there are many sound-only Japanese media where writing support isn't used; these include radio shows, podcasts, audiobooks, drama CDs etc. I've listened to a few Japanese drama CDs and had no trouble understanding them.

Comment: @SirTechSpec that said, I agree that in certain registers, such as academic talks and conferences, speech can get really muddled without kanji support. I chalk this to their using a writing-like proportion of kango, almost like using Classical Arabic etc. in formal occasions (Japanese people have corrected me, for example, for writing-derived speech tics like saying が rather than けど; the two kinds of Japanese are quite distinct; but there are a few situations where one "speaks written Japanese", and in these cases a transcription helps a lot, and may sometimes be a real necessity.)

Comment: I'll go against the trend but I completely disagree that "Kanji aren't necessary to write Japanese". You mention something about this in the "kanji can be cool" section, but I believe that classifying them as an "optional cool thing" is a huge overstatement. I understand that you're answer is probably meant to be mostly theoretical, and don't get me wrong I see the point. But, call me a traditionalist, I believe that kanji are the backbone of the Japanese language and they are too deeply intertwined with everything from culture to art to rule them out so simplistically as not necessary.

Comment: @Tommy: If kanji were necessary, the Tale of Genji couldn't have been written. I'm playing Final Fantasy VI right now, and it's all in kana; if kanji were necessary, I'd be unable to understand it, but anyone can. Read Matsunaga's research (cited above) for specific scientific proof on why it would be possible to forgo kanji, should they want to. Kanji is a choice, not a necessity. The Japanese language existed before it, and would exist without it; just like Korean or Vietnamese, which were once likewise intertwined with kanji.

Comment: Yeah don't get me wrong, I didn't mean yours is just an opinion and mine isn't. Quite the opposite. I admit indeed that what you say is mostly true. And right, it's a choice but it could be argued that if such choice was made (and maintained) maybe it comes from an underlying necessity that goes beyond being a cool embellishment. This is just my opinion of course. Without even mentioning how ugly a kana-only printed Japanese would look (and I say this as a shodou practitioner who actually loves kana). But this is another story.

Comment: Chinese people could not read pinyin (esp. people born outside China) `without tone marks` if you are a Hongkonger^^

Answer (score 24):

This is definitely a bit harder for native English speakers to pick up on at first, but sometimes homophones in Japanese are distinguishable by the pitch accent. So some of them aren't an issue at all. But of course some words do sound exactly the same. So how do you tell those apart? Easy: context.

Kanji aren't "necessary" to distinguish between homophones; they just help a bit in written text where you don't have pitch accent to help you. In reality, you don't technically need kanji at all. If you wrote a long essay in nothing but kana, everyone would be able to read it, albeit a bit slower. Since traditionally-written Japanese has no spaces, sometimes it can take a bit of closer reading to figure out when one word starts and another stops; but even to learners and especially to native speakers, this isn't too hard. In fact, it's not even unique to Japanese; back in the day, classical Latin and ancient Greek were also written without any spaces between words, and they managed just fine.

You mentioned using spaces as well; this is also something Japanese writers will do if they are writing in all kana. For example, all of the Pokemon games are written in nothing but kana because they knew lots of young kids would be playing it (though newer games do have an option to use kanji instead). In these games, words are actually separated by spaces, like you would see in Western writing. Note that in this case, particles like は and を, etc., are attached to the word they are modifying, not treated as a separate word or anything. Also, I'm not really sure why people would write わ as furigana over は when literally everyone knows that's how to read it. Additionally, を isn't always identical to お; there are still times when the pronunciations are distinct.

EDIT: Just to show what I'm talking about, here's Professor Oak asking if you're a boy or a girl.

[image]

Comment: I guess that is readable. But here's another question: Can you always rely on context to know what people are talking about? I get that you can figure out that おとこのこ would be 男の子, おんなのこ would be 女の子, and きみは would be 君は, but can you always rely on context to figure stuff out? Hmm, maybe I'm starting to like the idea of Kanji more.

Comment: English has homophones too, not as many as Japanese, sure, but we never have any problems distinguishing. I think probably you only think it would be hard to tell because you're only beginning. Once you start reading more, you'll see that almost always, there's only one parse of a sentence that actually makes sense.

Comment: +1, except for this part: "Additionally, を isn't always identical to お; there are still times when the pronunciations are distinct."

Comment: @snailplane Could you explain better why did you say this, please?

Comment: I'd also like to hear; especially in singing, people will frequently emphasize a "w" sound in を, and it's especially audible after ん in contrast to お.

Comment: @snailplane, Kurausukun: I've heard that before, and always wondered whether it wasn't conscious hypercorrection in the context of singing or public speeches etc. Like BBC announcers creating a pronunciation of "guerrilla" as distinct from "gorilla" to avoid sounding like "gorilla warfare".

Comment: @Macabeus The merger of を and お was completed around a thousand years ago, so it's not really accurate to say it's "still" distinguished.  Rather, the [w] *does* appears sometimes, but it's a modern phenomenon.  It appears as a spelling pronunciation, as a deliberate choice in singing, etc., but it doesn't seem like a phonemic distinction.  (I once read speculation that typing with romaji input has led to a resurgence in the pronunciation!  Who knows if that's true, though . . . )  Note that [w] is sometimes inserted before お as well as を in singing.

Comment: Portuguese also has a lot of homophones, too. "Concerto"  is musical presentation by an Orchestra. "Conserto" is a quick repair on something.  Both sound exactly the same but differ only by one letter - without context, it becomes very easy to mix them up. Same goes for "Cento" (One hundred) and Sento ("I sit"), and Saudar (to greet) and "Saldar" (to pay), etc.

Comment: @snailplane It's interesting that it's sort of "resurfaced" as a modern phenomenon. I can't say that I've ever heard someone sing an お with /w/ before it, though, and that is why I stand by my opinion that the two are distinct. But good catch, I'm not too brushed up on what periods of time had what phonetic changes.

Comment: 'This is definitely a bit harder for native English speakers to pick up on at first, but sometimes homophones in Japanese are distinguishable by the pitch accent. ' --> ah so this is actually giving further motivation to ask why we need or why it is helpful to use kanji?

Answer (score 6):

Thinking briefly, I think that there is no problem even if we have no kanji in Japanese to disambiguate homophones or homonyms as OP thinks , but in fact we need kanji.

In conversation, not in writing, it is quite natural that people in the conversation hope the conversation goes smoothly. Therefore, we usually avoid using words that might cause ambiguities to listeners like homonyms. Also, just after a homonym we used, we often complement the ambiguity with another word or expression similar to the homonym. In addition, when a listener wonders in what meaning of multiple meanings of a homonym, the listener would ask unknown points to the other party. Furthermore, when speaking, if we think that the partner in the conversaion has misunderstood the homonym we used, we will try to resolve the misunderstanding soon with another expression.

In this way, there are many advantageous conditions in conversation different from writing, so homonyms can be used without kanji even in conversation.

As the conclusion, therefore, it is not possible to discuss whether kanji is necessary or not for homonyms because conversation and writing are not used under the same condition.

Comment: I was thinking along this line too, but I had trouble resolving it with the idea of speeches.  If you are giving a speech to hundreds of people, your opportunities to disambiguate and your opportunities to avoid ambiguities would seem to be roughly the same as they would be if you printed the words and had the hundreds of people read it.

Comment: @CortAmmon: Regarding homonyms, I think that it is most difficult to talk in front of a large number of people when you compare the three of (1) speaking in front of a large audience, (2) talking in conversation, and (3) writing. In general, however, I think that we could have enough time to prepare to talk in front of a large number of people. In talking, the problem to convey homonyms with the intended meaning, is the same condition for any language having homonyms not only as Japanese and English. It is a good occasion where the skill of the speaker is demonstrated.

Answer (score 6):

Most everyone's answers are correct, but I wanted to bring up one useful aspect of kanji which I don't think has been brought up. It may be limited to learners like me, but many times when I encounter new words in kanji (in manga, online, paper forms at the doctor's office, etc...) I've found that I can understand what is being conveyed even without knowing how to pronounce that word because I know what the kanji mean.

In a recent example, a native Japanese friend was helping me with understanding a dentist form, and didn't know the English phrase "receding gum line." I had no idea what the word for "gums" even was in Japanese, but I saw 歯肉 ("tooth" and "meat" or "flesh"), and I immediately could understand that we were talking about gums, which helped us figure it out.

If this had all been written in kana, and I didn't know what しにく meant already -- or if I were speaking to someone over the phone and only heard the word -- it would have taken more time and more explanation, and possibly a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Stop signs could also be just the word "STOP" written on a white rectangular sign, but would you argue the necessity of using a RED octagon? Probably, not, because human brains recognize shapes faster than words that we have to read to our selves and then get the meaning. Native English speakers can skim thuorgh lines of text beaucse they are able to recgnoize words by their gerneal shapes.

However in Japanese language that does not have spaces, they need other forms of grouping characters that only represent a certain sound, into something with a context. Conveniently, there is a language that has been doing that for quite a long time, hence Chinese. So Japanese borrowed some characters that have similar meaning or pronunciation and assigned the Hiragana to them (hey at least that's what I think happened, THIS IS NOT A FACT, CHINESE/JAPANESE DON'T KILL ME)

Personally, as a Chinese that studied Japanese, I find myself reading at least 5 times slower if I'm reading texts for "beginners" or "kids", because I would have to read the Hiragana in my head and then recognize the context by the sound (PS: not related but Romaji are the worst, I have to translate to Japanese then do the things). While with Kanji I can skim though the general "shape" of the character and know the meaning, just like knowing red light means stop.

Comment: Korean squared this circle by simply introducing spaces when they jettisoned mixed script.